# can help me to generate multiple mpdf files with loop without lose configuration?

Tags: php, zend-framework, dompdf, mpdf, laravel-dompdf

[Image to be attached to PDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OuxYQ.png)

can help me to generate multiple mpdf files with loop without lose configuration, because it always write first file correct but the others with attached image contain splitted arabic characters?

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) 
and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), 
then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), 
the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and 
how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

just go the mpdf/classes/otl.php and replace include_once to include. that's all.